# Infinite loop when passing parameter to a controller function from view - codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I didn't find any answer to my problem, which is I think pretty specific.

Here's the deal, I'm creating a simple table in a view and one column contains a button which link to a controller function which has a parameter.

Here's how I call the function:

```
<?php echo base_url()survey/survey_modification/$numsurvey ;?>
```

This is in a button balise, which is in a foreach loop, and the $numsurvey will not be the same for each button created.

Here's the prototype of the controller function:

```
public function survey_modification($numsurvey);
```

The $numsurvey is base64 encoded and yet, when I'm clicking on the button (any button) it loads the page, but also loads infinite copies of the same page (you can basically scroll down infinitely).

I know it happens when I'm passing a parameter to my function but I don't why so I'm counting on you to tell me the way to properly do it.

I have find a way to get around the problem but this is not satisfying enough (pass the $numsurvey with the get method /controller/function?numsurvey=$numsurvey).

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT (my function):

```
public function survey_modification($numsurvey) {
    $data = array();
    $data['active_page'] = "modify_survey";
    $data['meta_title'] = "Modify Survey";
    $data['numsurvey'] = $numsurvey;
    $numsurvey_decode = $this->encryption->decrypt(base64url_decode($numsurvey));
    $data['phpvar'] = $this->Template_model->fetchPhpVar($numsurvey_decode);
    $data['questions'] = $this->Survey_model->fetch_question_survey($numsurvey_decode);
    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['error_img'] = 0;

    $this->create_header($data);
    $this->create_top($data);
    $this->create_left($data);
    $this->load->view('survey/modify_survey', $data);
    $this->create_footer($data);
}
```

[The page with infinite version of itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXyZK.png)

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code in your `survey_modification` function to see why it's create an infinite number of pages.

Comment: I'm editing right now to show you, but I have commented all my code inside the function and it stills loop.

Comment: Is it infinite or just r-e-a-l-l-y long? Is there an error message at the bottom of the page (or anywhere)? What actually repeats over and over? Sounds like the view or create_whatever() is calling itself.